# SSRS How to provide multiple values to Query Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Im trying to pass multiple parameters to a Shared DataSet.
I am using visual studio and microsoft reporting services projects.

The query of the dataset is as follows

[image: DataSetQuery]

So the 'MC.MaterialTypeCode in (@MaterialTypeCode)' has the parameter that can contain multiple values.

I defined the parameter as follows:

[image: DataSetParameters]

In the report I am using this dataset and providing fixed parameters.

[image]

The idea is to use the same shared dataset with different report datasets.
(SupplyPaper_A4_Tier1, SupplyPaper_A4_Tier2)

I'm trying to provide multiple parameters 'Roll', 'Cutsheet' but this does not seem to work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of values to the parameter so try this as the parameter value

Click the `fx` button next to the parameter value field and then use this expression

```
=SPLIT("Roll,CutSheet", ",")
```

I've just tested this and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Wow, would never have found this. It works perfectly, thank you very much!